# Proxychains won't work with NordVPN socks5 proxy

Tags: linux, firefox, proxy, kali-linux

I've been trying to get to use NordVPN socks5 from their servers. 
My `proxychains.conf` looks like this:

```
# proxychains.conf  VER 3.1
#
#        HTTP, SOCKS4, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.
#   

# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted
#
#dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
strict_chain
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#random_chain
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

# Make sense only if random_chain
#chain_len = 2

# Quiet mode (no output from library)
#quiet_mode

# Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns 

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

# ProxyList format
#       type  host  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#               socks5  192.168.67.78   1080    lamer   secret
#               http    192.168.89.3    8080    justu   hidden
#               socks4  192.168.1.49    1080
#               http    192.168.39.93   8080
#
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )
#
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
#socks4     127.0.0.1 9050
socks5  us100.nordvpn.com.tcp443.ovpn 1080 username password
```

Using `proxychains firefox`, I launch Firefox,
but it won't load anything. 
How can I get proxychains to work in Firefox with the NordVPN proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you need to use the IP address of the NordVPN server not the DNS address. This is easily found by pinging the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following config:

```
http    ip_address    port_number    email_or_username    password
```

You can check the IP address here: https://www.whatismyip.com/dns-lookup/, you need to enter for instance us2330.nordvpn.com or any other server you want. 
And with https://www.whatismyip.com/port-scanner/ you can check if port 80 is available.

To check if it works you can execute the following command: `proxychains curl ifconfig.me/ip`